# Tick box with macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

please how to make tick box in excel make work with "2 macros"?

I need it, when checked, then hide some rows, and when unchecked, then unhide it. How can I do that?

I have this macro:

```
Sub bodnariucova_jednotlivci()
    Columns("U:EW").Hidden = True
End Sub
```

[image: tick box]

EDIT: I edited it like this

```
Sub bodnariucova_jednotlivci()
    Dim cBox As CheckBox

    Set cBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(LName)

    If cBox.Value > 0 Then
    Columns("U:EZ").Hidden = True

    Else
      Columns("U:EZ").Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

But when I run it I get Run-time error '1004' Can not get properties CheckBoxes of class Worksheet (something like that, just in my language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not two macros, you can do this in one. But have to ensure that you use a CheckBox from the ActiveX-Toolbar.

**Edit:** Insert new CheckBox, right click it and choose "Show code" (or similar in your language). The new Checkbox gets a name like `CheckBox1` and the shown macro is named therefore `CheckBox1_Click()`.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
   If CheckBox1.Value = True then
       Columns("U:EW").Hidden = True
   Else 
       Columns("U:EW").Hidden = False
   End If
End Sub
```

And with some boolean logic you can simplify this macro:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Columns("U:EW").Hidden = CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I click it, nothing is happening (?).

Comment: Yes I did and tried both variants.

Comment: Edited my answer with all steps which I have done.

Comment: Yes, thats it. With that CheckBox1 it worked. Maybe I should have renamed that check box as well as the name in the code?

Comment: It seems to be a difference between a CheckBox of the ActiveX-toolbar and that of the Contol elements-Toolbar. I didn't manage to get it worked with this other checkbox.